# WSO2 IOT APIMClientOAuthException error

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have uploaded WSO2 IoTS 3.2.0 in a remote virtual machine (Ubuntu 16.04) with a static IP.

I run the script `./change-ip.sh`, then change `localhost` to my IP address.

But when I try to launch to the device management console, I have this error:

```
An Error Occurred!
HTTP Status : 500
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.integration.client.exception.APIMClientOAuthException: failed to retrieve oauth token using jwt
```

I saw in the WSO2 documentation and many answers about that, to avoid this problem we must not refer the IP address we defined to another hostname in the `/etc/hosts` file.

But I have not referred my IP to a hostname, here is my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       mdm01.office.utils.dgtck.net
```

Can someone help me please?